# Is there any other less processor intensive way to limit the speed at which a function is called other than busy-waiting?

Tags: c++

If I wanted to limit the calling of a function `f()`, say, no less than once per 10 seconds, I would do this:

```
while(true)
{
    int start = get_seconds_elapsed();

    f()

    int end = get_seconds_elapsed();

    while(end - start < 10)
    {
        end = get_seconds_elapsed()
    }
}
```

The problem with this, of course, is that it will take up one full-core of the processor it's running on. My question is, is there any other less processor intensive way I can go about doing this?

Edit: I meant no **less** than once per second, I mistyped.

Comment: [`std::thread::sleep_for()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) is purposed to do so.

Comment: C++11 has timing functions like `sleep_until`.

Comment: POSIX systems have [sleep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sleep.html) and you might want [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html). Your question is probably operating system specific.

Comment: _@nooble_ I have extended my answer a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"My question is, is there any other less processor intensive way I can go about doing this?"*

In standard c++ you can use [`std::thread::sleep_for()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for), or [`std::this_thread::sleep_until`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until) to realize non busy waits.

---

> *"I meant no **less** than once per second"*

As from their sample, to execute no less than once per second you can use

```
 using namespace std::literals;
 std::this_thread::sleep_for(990ms); // Sleep for at least 990 milliseconds.
```

In the sample above, I took a value below 1s, because the function has inaccuracies depending on the underlying operating system platform. How much these can be exactly depends, but expecting 10ms tolerance is a good value of thumb.

Comment: If you really need to limit the wait to 1000ms, then 990ms is cutting it fine, I would say.I would use something like 900ms. There is still no guarantee, but you are giving the operating system a sporting chance.

Answer (score 0):

```
// adjust the makefile LDLIBS to include "-lboost_thread"
// so this will compile and work

int someSeconds = 1;

boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(someSeconds));
```